# JavaMail > Jakarta Mail >?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jakarta-mail

The current homepage of Jakarta Mail (https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/mail/docs/api/) is no longer working.

I have heard that the name has changed to Eclipse Angus.

What is the status of it?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current homepage of Jakarta EE is available at https://jakarta.ee/

Clicking *Specifications* > *Browse Specifications* brings you to https://jakarta.ee/specifications/

Scroll/Ctrl+F to "Jakarta Mail" and you'll find it points to  https://jakarta.ee/specifications/mail/

It says that the currently latest version is 2.1 and it links to https://jakarta.ee/specifications/mail/2.1/

Over there it says that there's only one compatible implementation, which happens to be Angus:

> #### Compatible Implementations
>
> - [Angus Mail 1.0.0](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/angus-mail/releases/tag/1.0.0)